# How to force div element to keep its contents inside container

Tags: html, css

I am making a css menu. For this I am using a `ul`. When I make `li` float left then all `li`'s gets outside of the ul. I mean the height of `ul` become zero. How can I make `li` display inside `ul` after giving float left.

One way to do is to make a `div` tag with some common class and add clear: both to it in css but I do not want this.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Just add `overflow: auto;` to the `<ul>`. That will make it so that the text doesn't leak outside of the UL.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/6cKAG/

---

However, depending on what you're doing, it might be easier to just make the `<li>` `display: inline;`. It totally depends on what you're doing!

See: http://jsfiddle.net/k7Wqx/

Answer (score 11):

If you define `float` to your child then you have to clear your parent. Write `overflow:hidden` to your UL.

```
ul{
 overflow:hidden;
}
```

**OR**
You can also use `clearfix` method for this:

```
ul:after{
 content:'';
 clear:both;
 display:block;
}
```

Read this http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/

Comment: Who give me a downvote please explain the reason. what's wrong in my answer thanks :)

Comment: I believe it's also recommended to add `zoom:1` to the first ruleset for IE - otherwise, it's `overflow` misbehaves in versions < IE9 (also curious about the down-vote).

Comment: @TiesonT. :after work till IE8 & OP define css3 in his question which means. He want to support modern browsers

Comment: Or he just got carried away with his tags, since he's not really doing anything CSS3-specific. Still, you are correct, good sir (hence my up-vote). :)

Comment: The clearfix method is the best approach when your `overflow:hidden` is actually hiding contents instead.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the overflowing text in the div to automatically newline instead of being hidden or making a scrollbar, use the

```
word-wrap: break-word
```

property.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when floated elements (menu items) are positioned inside a non-floating container (`ul`).

This could either be fixed by floating the container as well (rarely acceptable), or [applying a clearfix](https://stackoverflow.com/q/211383/1081234) which addresses exactly this issue.